# Crystal Report using local database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I m creating crystal report in C# by using local database. I have done all connections. When i run my application, datas r inserted in the table. But table Data is not binded in the CrystalReportView. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Please try following link,

[Crystal report 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/letaonarticle2.aspx)

[Crystal report 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/MySQLCrystal.aspx)

If you want more help please ask me....